Call a function if a Rust trait is implemented, do nothing otherwise
I am surprisingly stuck on a Rust problem that looks counterintuitively simple, and yet I cannot seem to figure it out. I am nearly starting to think it might be unsolvable, and yet I'm not sure what are the fundamental reasons, if any, why it should be.
Say I have a trait
trait T {
    fn t(&self);
}

I would like to implement a generic function f<X>(x: &X) such that:

If x implements T, f invokes x.t();
If x does not implement T, f does nothing.

I feel so inexplicably lost. Of course, two implementations of f will not work because of duplicate definitions. I thought about adding an helper trait H with some function h that by default does nothing, then implementing H for every X: T, overloading h to invoke x.t(). But, then every X that does not implement T would not implement H either, so that doesn't help. Right?
Am I missing something? Is implementing f possible, but very convoluted? Or is there any fundamental reason why implementing f should be impossible altogether?
(If possible, I'd like to avoid dynamic dispatch, as this is quite an intensely used part of my code. But, at this point, I'll go with whatever's possible!)

This is called specialization, and is not possible with today's Rust.

You can use downcast and downcast_mut from Any to test if the contained value is of a given type:
use std::any::Any;

trait T {
    fn t(&self);
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

struct TCode;

impl T for TCode {
    fn t(&self) {
        println!("hello");
    }
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = TCode {};
    if let Some(TCode {}) = x.as_any().downcast_ref::<TCode>() {
        x.t()
    }
}

Playground

This makes a lot of sense. It does involve dynamic dispatch, correct? I suspected there might be no way around it. Do you think there's a chance the compiler will optimize the dynamic dispatch away?

There is no dynamic dispatching for the generic defined parameter fn t(&self); because the type of the trait  TCode is is not used with the dyn keyword, see monomorphism. But the downcasting to an TCode object must happen at runtime, because the concrete type of our object is unknown at compile time.

This is not exactly what you want, but perhaps it is good enough and otherwise gives you a chance to clarify your needs.
trait T {
    fn for_real() -> bool;
    fn t(&self);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SpecialA;

impl T for SpecialA {
    fn for_real() -> bool {
        true
    }
    fn t(&self) {
        dbg!(self);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct OrdinaryA;

impl T for OrdinaryA {
    fn for_real() -> bool {
        false
    }
    fn t(&self) {
        dbg!(self);
    }
}

fn f<X: T>(x: &X) {
    if <X as T>::for_real() {
        x.t();
    }
}

fn main() {
    f(&SpecialA);
    f(&OrdinaryA);
}


Why not just have a method with a default implementation that does nothing? No need for two methods.

@ChayimFriedman, would that work if the return type is not actually ()?

No, but I assume whatever you put there doesn't need a return type, since if it needs one you will have to create one anyway.

If you can constrain f's type parameter to implementors of T then on "ordinary" implementations you only need leave the body of t empty: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=55fdd1b46ebd6514278bca2322aaefa7
